# Business Object report to excel using webservices : DocID and ReportID?

Tags: web-services, rest, business-objects

I'm wondering in this RESTful request to BO : GET http://:6405/biprws/raylight/vx/documents/{documentId}/reports/{reportId}

What are {documentId} and {reportId} ?

On the documentation they say :

> **Note**: {documentId}: The identifier of the Web Intelligence document
>   retrieved in the document list by: GET
>   http://:6405/biprws/raylight/vx/documents   **Note**:
>   {reportId}: The identifier of the Web Intelligence document report
>   retrieved in the document's reports list by: GET
>   http://:6405/biprws/raylight/vx/documents/{documen
>   tId}/reports

But it won't work. Also I don't really see the point of requesting all documents and reports ID while I want to get one.

**Question** : Is there a way to get document and report IDs from launchPad.

I supposed they're ID and CUID on a document properties but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is often confusion about the difference between **document** and **report**, in BusinessObjects WebI terminology.

**Documents** are independent reporting objects, associated with a single .wid file.  When you look at a folder in BI launch pad, you are looking at a list of **documents**.  A document will have one or more **reports**, which are represented by tabs in a document.

So this request:

http://server:6405/biprws/raylight/v1/documents/123456/reports/2

will retrieve the report (tab) with ID #2, from WebI document with ID #123456.

Note that the reportid may or may not be an index.  You can't assume that calling .../reports/2 will retrieve the second report tab.  You must first call .../documents/x/reports to get a list of available reports and associated IDs.

The documentid can be retrieved from BI launch pad or CMC; simply right-click on a report and hit properties -- the ID and CUID will be there.